# Using google prettify in bootstrap website with php pages

Tags: php, format, code-snippets, prettify

I have a bootstrap website with css built in and am trying to implement google prettify as described on this tutorial: http://www.techinfected.net/2016/12/syntax-highlighting-with-code-prettify.html

The problem is, that my website employs php main pages, and while certain sub pages are html, I want a way to add prettify in the css, so that everytime I use the < pre > and < / pre> tags, the code snippets will be formatted.

I have the following css files, and have tried changing the code where the "pre" tags are mentioned, but to no avail.

[image]

The pages that I wish to format include python code snippets inserted into html. (see format screenshot below) *for instance, the content file contains code snippets using the < pre > tag
[image]

These pages are "Controlled" by a php page in the main public_html, for example:
[image]

Can anyone provide some insight into how to go about adding css or automating the process of getting formatted code on using the pre tags, with or without google prettify.

**Contents of the code.css file**

```
   /* http://prismjs.com/download.html?themes=prism&languages=markup+css+clike+javascript+abap+actionscript+ada+apacheconf+apl+applescript+asciidoc+aspnet+autoit+autohotkey+bash+basic+batch+c+brainfuck+bro+bison+csharp+cpp+coffeescript+ruby+css-extras+d+dart+diff+docker+eiffel+elixir+erlang+fsharp+fortran+gherkin+git+glsl+go+graphql+groovy+haml+handlebars+haskell+haxe+http+icon+inform7+ini+j+jade+java+json+julia+keyman+kotlin+latex+less+livescript+lolcode+lua+makefile+markdown+matlab+mel+mizar+monkey+nasm+nginx+nim+nix+nsis+objectivec+ocaml+oz+parigp+parser+pascal+perl+php+php-extras+powershell+processing+prolog+properties+protobuf+puppet+pure+python+q+qore+r+jsx+rest+rip+roboconf+crystal+rust+sas+sass+scss+scala+scheme+smalltalk+smarty+sql+stylus+swift+tcl+textile+twig+typescript+verilog+vhdl+vim+wiki+xojo+yaml */
    /**
     * prism.js default theme for JavaScript, CSS and HTML
     * Based on dabblet (http://dabblet.com)
     * @author Lea Verou
     */

    code[class*="language-"],
    pre[class*="language-"] {
        color: black;
        background: none;
        text-shadow: 0 1px white;
        font-family: Consolas, Monaco, 'Andale Mono', 'Ubuntu Mono', monospace;
        text-align: left;
        white-space: pre;
        word-spacing: normal;
        word-break: normal;
        word-wrap: normal;
        line-height: 1.5;

        -moz-tab-size: 4;
        -o-tab-size: 4;
        tab-size: 4;

        -webkit-hyphens: none;
        -moz-hyphens: none;
        -ms-hyphens: none;
        hyphens: none;
    }

    pre[class*="language-"]::-moz-selection, pre[class*="language-"] ::-moz-selection,
    code[class*="language-"]::-moz-selection, code[class*="language-"] ::-moz-selection {
        text-shadow: none;
        background: #b3d4fc;
    }

    pre[class*="language-"]::selection, pre[class*="language-"] ::selection,
    code[class*="language-"]::selection, code[class*="language-"] ::selection {
        text-shadow: none;
        background: #b3d4fc;
    }

    @media print {
        code[class*="language-"],
        pre[class*="language-"] {
            text-shadow: none;
        }
    }

    /* Code blocks */
    pre[class*="language-"] {
        padding: 12em;
        margin: .5em 0;
        overflow: auto;
    }

    :not(pre) > code[class*="language-"],
    pre[class*="language-"] {
        background: #f5f2f0;
    }

    /* Inline code */
    :not(pre) > code[class*="language-"] {
        padding: .1em;
        border-radius: .13em;
        white-space: normal;
    }

    .token.comment,
    .token.prolog,
    .token.doctype,
    .token.cdata {
        color: slategray;
    }

    .token.punctuation {
        color: #999;
    }

    .namespace {
        opacity: .7;
    }

    .token.property,
    .token.tag,
    .token.boolean,
    .token.number,
    .token.constant,
    .token.symbol,
    .token.deleted {
        color: #905;
    }

    .token.selector,
    .token.attr-name,
    .token.string,
    .token.char,
    .token.builtin,
    .token.inserted {
        color: #690;
    }

    .token.operator,
    .token.entity,
    .token.url,
    .language-css .token.string,
    .style .token.string {
        color: #a67f59;
        background: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, .5);
    }

    .token.atrule,
    .token.attr-value,
    .token.keyword {
        color: #07a;
    }

    .token.function {
        color: #DD4A68;
    }

    .token.regex,
    .token.important,
    .token.variable {
        color: #e90;
    }

    .token.important,
    .token.bold {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .token.italic {
        font-style: italic;
    }

    .token.entity {
        cursor: help;
    }
```

Comment: useful question. Assume you have tried to edit and change the pre code in the css, as you mentioned, but it had no effect? What is in the custom.css?

Comment: Not much in custom.css: .vertical-line {
 border-right: thick-solid #ff0000;
}